# How to Detect Phone numbers in Message (String) , highlight them & allow user to call those numbers in Android?

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching, linkify

Currently I'm developing an Android app which receives Message from server side (as a Push Notification) & store those messages in database .

These messages are displayed in List as shown & each message needs to have functionality which allows user to call numbers displayed in message .

WHAT I have tried so far:

1. Used Linkify to highlight number & it allows user to redirect to phone dialer screen with number pre-loaded . My requirement is to call directly without navigating to dialer . I know it is not recommended way to call directly but this app must have this functionality .

2.Pattern matching :

```
    String regex = "^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$"; // Also tried [^-?0-9]+
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mText);`
```

Probably I''m making mistake at pattern matching as it is not displaying any number from message.

**Sample Message 1 :** "Please Call Paul on these numbers  : 900-445-1549 Or on another number : 797-2436-2455 to support".

**Sample Message 2 :** "Please Call Paul on this number  : 900-445-1549 to support".

So, basically I would like to detect above two numbers / one number from message , highlight those & able to call directly on tapping.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

1. Programatically

   ```
   Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
   ```
2. In Xml file

   ```
   android:autoLink="phone"
   ```

Comment: I have already tried Linkify but it navigates user to dialer screen . Please read my entire question & what I want to achieve .

Comment: you want call directly on click of phone number right?